# Find the eigvenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to do my homework and getting pretty frustrated with this one.

The question follows as:
Find the eigenvalues λ1<λ2 and associated unit eigenvectors u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub> of the symmetric matrix A = \begin{array}{cc}
7 &-6\cr
-6 &-2
\end{array}

I'm getting eigenvalues of -5 and 10, which are correct. But it says my unit eigenvectors [1,2] and [-2, 1] respectively, are incorrect. [WolframAlpha also says mine are correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B7,-6%5D,%5B-6,-2%5D%5D%20eigenvector), which leads to more confusion.

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You aren't reading closely enough: your eigenvectors aren't **unit** vectors. You need to normalize them, if it's asking for **unit** eigenvectors.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh, what a simple mistake. Thanks!